# Directing users to specific pages on login

Tags: mysql

How can I direct different users to specific pages, using HTML, PHP, and MYSQL? I need a login page that will do that. The code is logging in but to only one common page.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta id="_moz_html_fragment">
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(ocean5.jpeg)">
<div style="text-align: center;"><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<big><big>LETTER&nbsp; HEAD SYSTEM<br>
<br>
<br>
</big></big>
<form method="post" action="view.php">
<center>
<table width="30%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">USERNAME<br>
</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">PASSWORD<br>
</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password"><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<form method="post" action="view.php">
<input value="LOGIN" name="submit" type="submit"><br>
</form>
</center>
</form>
<big><big><br>
</big></big></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have hr, legal and md folders that contain different files.but currently all users can view all the files. they  only need to view what belongs to them.

Comment: Clear output (using output buffers) and send a `Header('Location: ...);`

Comment: on it.let me try that see if it works.

Comment: that means i need to create a php login code?